# Remove auto-suggestion and it's layout

Tags: android, keyboard, autosuggest

Hi I've been asked to remove the keyboard's auto-suggestion to save the screen space. I've managed to disable the auto suggest using

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"`

but the layout is still shown, just no word suggestions. How can I tell the keyboard to hide the entire layout for auto suggestions?
[image: this is how it looks]

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

I tried this and checked on lollipop. it doesn't show the suggestion bar

Comment: thanks I've tried this but it didn't help. have a look at the pic I've added

Answer (score 0):

Using
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
removes the autosuggest layout